# What does "up to proportionality" mean exactly?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Using the "site:"-specific Google search, I have searched both MO and math.SE for the word, "proportionality," and have noticed the phrase "up to proportionality" in many posts.

What does "up to proportionality" mean exactly? A link to its source would be nice.

Comment: For example, a certain constant is so (i.e. constant) "up to proportionalty" because its value may change if we change the units of measure involved.

Comment: "There is, up to proportionality, a unique triangle with all edges the same length." Something like that?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430543/how-do-i-understand-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-up-to-in-mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Up to" is usually used when two things only differ in superficial or removable ways relative to the focus of the discussion/proof/etc. Indefinite integrals are the same up to a constant. Lines are the same up to a choice of basis. You can find it on wikipedia's [jargon page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon). Also it has its [own page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to).

Comment: The jargon page link is very limited in what it says about "up to". I would link the page that wikipedia has [explicitly on this phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context. It usually means that the answer of a problem is only well-defined up to a constant. For example when you compute an eigenvector of matrix, the vector $v$ is equivalent with the vector $5\cdot v$, so one might write a sentence like "the eigenvector is $\dots$ up to proportionality".